# How to get next id for ID generation strategy = GenerationType.TABLE

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

Is there an easy way to get the next id of an object which use id generation strategy GenerationType.TABLE and a custom database table? My problem is that allocation size is not 1 (which is fine - optimization), but this way JPA doesn't update the sequence table on every object creation. So I'm wondering is there a way to hit next sequence ( I need it for different operation) and next time new object is created it should use next sequence as well. So id which I will use for different purpose will be skipped next time a new object is created.

Example of the mapping:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TestIdGenerator")
  @GenericGenerator(
      name = "TestIdGenerator",
      strategy = "enhanced-table",
      parameters = {
          @Parameter(name = "table_name", value = "sequences"),
          @Parameter(name = "segment_column_name", value = "key_column_txt"),
          @Parameter(name = "segment_value", value = "test_id"),
          @Parameter(name = "value_column_name", value = "next_id"),
          @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "20"),
          @Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "pooled-lo")
      }
  )
  @Column(name = "test_id")
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  @ToString.Include
  private Integer id;
```

I'm using SequenceStyleGenerator (Hibernate 5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just invoking the same code that Hibernate does? Something like this:

```java
Integer nextValue = (Integer) session.getSessionFactory()
  .unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class)
  .getRuntimeMetamodels()
  .getMappingMetamodel()
  .findEntityDescriptor(MyEntity.class)
  .getIdentifierGenerator()
  .generate(session, null)
```

Comment: Yeah, I did the same, couldn't find better solution, so this is the right answer.